# automapper: Mapping complex source class tocomplex derived classes

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper

```
    [DataContract]
    public class SupplierView : BaseView
    {   
        [DataMember]
        Public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        Public ApprovedSupplierView approvedSupplier { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        Public AdHocSupplierView adhocsupplier { get; set; }
        //other fields...
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class ContextSupplierView : SupplierView //Working
    {   
        [DataMember]
        Public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        //New fields added
        [DataMember]
        Public ContextApprovedSupplierView contextApprovedSupplier { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        Public ContextAdHocSupplierView contextAdhocsupplier { get; set; }
        //other fields...
    }
    public class ApprovedSupplierView :  BaseView
    {   
        [DataMember]
        Public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        Public string Phone { get; set; }




    [DataContract]
    public class ContextSupplierView : SupplierView //Not working
    {   
        [DataMember]
        Public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        Public new ContextApprovedSupplierView approvedSupplier { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        Public new ContextAdHocSupplierView adhocsupplier { get; set; }
        //other fields...
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ContextApprovedSupplierView :  ApprovedSupplierView
    {   
        [DataMember]
        Public string ContextDescription { get; set; }

    SupplierView supplierObject = new SupplierView(Linq populates this correctly);
    Mapper.CreateMap<SupplierView, ContextSupplierView>();
    claimContext.Supplier = Mapper.Map<ContextSupplierView>(supplierObject);
```

I have a project which already gets the Supplier and its nested types from the database, but how can I use automapper to copy everything into a ContextSupplier which has ContextApprovedSupplier approvedSupplier and ContextAdHocSupplier adHocSupplier But that gives:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: ApprovedSupplierView -> ContextApprovedSupplierView
>   TotalSystemsPlc.Bluescape.Claims.DataContracts.Views.ProjectLoadViews.ApprovedSupplierView
>   -> TotalSystemsPlc.Bluescape.Claims.DataContracts.Views.ContextViews.ContextApprovedSupplierView
>
> Destination path:
>   ContextSupplierView.ApprovedSupplier.ApprovedSupplier
>
> Source value:
>   TotalSystemsPlc.Bluescape.Claims.DataContracts.Views.ProjectLoadViews.ApprovedSupplierView

If I create new fields contextApprovedSupplier and contextAdhocsupplier, it automapper populates ApprovedSupplier and Adhocsupplier which can be mapped individually but I'd rather do it all in one command.
Any help would be greatfully received as I have been trying for hours to do this!!!

EDIT: Apologies, please find the correct hierarchy now!

Comment: what is `SupplierView` and `ContextSupplierView`?

Comment: Shoudn't `ContextSupplier` be derived from `Supplier`? If no then provide the `Base` class that declares hidden properties `approvedSupplier` `adhocsupplier`

Comment: You can try adding mapping: `Mapper.CreateMap<ApprovedSupplierView, ContextApprovedSupplier>()` yet shouldn't your view in this case return `ContextApprovedSupplierView`?

Comment: @Rafal - yes i want the original to map to the derived class

Comment: @AndrewDay does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

@Rafal Adding the mappings together really worked, thank you very much!

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SupplierView, ContextSupplierView>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ApprovedSupplierView, ContextApprovedSupplierView>();
Mapper.CreateMap<AdHocSupplierView, ContextAdHocSupplierView>();
```

I also had to add a default constructor as that issues an error which refers to a missing cast! I look forward to using Automapper more now.